# How can I extract both column from View named "Max_part_supplied'?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have created a view named 'Max_part_supplied' which consists of two column as
**Number_of_parts** and **Supplier_name**.
I am trying to access the **Supplier_name**  who supplies maximum number of parts, as

```
select MAX(Number_of_parts) as max_part, Supplier_name
from Max_part_supplied;
```

This is the view `Max_part_supplied`

```
Number_of_parts   Supplier_name    
1                 Ambani Traders    
3                 Lalu Traders    
2                 Paltu Traders    
1                 Sunil Traders
```

But I am getting error message as

> Msg 8120,Level 16,State 1,line 84
> Column **Max_part_supplied.Supplier_name** is invalid in the select list because it is not containted
> in either aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: The error is very clear and tells you the solution - what are you unsure about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your view already has the `max` per supplier, you just want the maximum of these?

```
select top (1) Number_of_parts, Supplier_name
from Max_part_supplied
order by Number_of_parts desc
```

If you want all suppliers in the event two or more have the same max, use `top (1) with ties`